# How to Update database from UI which has many textboxes and CheckBox in asp.net and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to ASP.net. I have a webform where I have 40 text box 18 drop downs and 29 checkbox. I need to load the all data from these controls to SQL server database table using stored procedure. I dont want to pass all the parameters one by one and update the table.

Is there any other short way to do it? Please help

Comment: *I dont want to pass all the parameters one by one* - why? At the very least you can't escape from reading each of those control values, right!

Comment: I mean is there a way if i can load all the data from the control to datatable and then update the table to DB?

Comment: Yes. If you use the MVC model, it goes and generates most of that stuff for you automatically. It passes things around using something called model binding which means you generally don't need to hand map everything

Comment: @Avinash you need to additionally add a tag to clarify if you are using `mvc` or `web forms`.

Comment: its Webforms not MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I follow your question here?

The simplest way, would be to do a model object. Create a method that accepts the model object that includes all the data from your form. This methods feeds the stored procedure call.
This is the common way to do it. And the fastest. You need to assign the data to data-fields. There is no way around it really. But of course it can be done in many different ways. 
So you want a more specific answer, you will have to elaborate what you mean by:

> "I dont want to pass all the parameters one by one and update the
>   table."

I can't come up with a scenario where it would be desireable to pass each parameter one by one into an update statement...

but you will have to mention each field in your SQL stored procedure, that you want to update.

if that is your only question:

```
UPDATE table-name 
SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
WHERE condition
```

Comment: Thanks @mortenbork. if you can send me a example link, that would help me a lot

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access

This is a good guide for beginners. It uses alot of visual studios UI elements and such.

Be aware there is likely more modern approaches out there, that are balanced towards specific performance requirements. But this will get the job done.

Comment: @Avinash the above comment was meant for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used a model in your view and used Razor syntax to render the relevant controls than if you have a form defined, posting back to the controller that accepts the same model as it's parameter will handle the binding of all the properties back to the model.

You then either parse the model or use the properties and send them down to entity framework, or any other ORM that you might be using, and have it handle the update operation.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourPostMethod(YourModelUsedInView model)
{
    // process your model here and send it down to the DB.
}
```